# How to determine whether an object is a sequence

Tags: python, collections, python-3.x

I can think of *two* ways to determine whether an object is a sequence:

- `hasattr(object, '__iter__')`.
- And whether calling `iter(object)` raises a `TypeError`.

As it is most Pythonic to *ask forgiveness* than to *ask permission*, I'd use the second idiom, although I consider it more ugly (additionally, raising an exception once you've caught the `TypeError` to determine that the object isn't a sequence would yield an undesirable "double-exception" stack trace).

Ultimately, is checking that an object defines an `__iter__` method exhaustive enough to determine whether an object is a sequence? (In older versions of Python, for example, `str` didn't define an `__iter__` method; I've also heard that some objects can also simply define and use `__getitem__` without defining an `__iter__` and act like a sequence.) Or is defining `__iter__` *the contract* of a sequence?

Comment: Of what I could find online, [this discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/514838-how-test-if-object-sequence-iterable) seemed most relevant, although it's quite old; [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-or-tuple-but-not-string) was somewhat related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isinstance(obj, collections.Sequence)`. [Abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) are exactly for this. They didn't exist prior to 2.6 though. In case you're forced to use older versions, you're out of luck and better stick with EAFP.

Comment: +1. I was literally about to post the same thing. But note that in the pre-2.6 case, non-sequences have `__iter__`, e.g. `dict`. I'm not sure on what the best way to deal with this is.

Comment: The best way to deal with it might be documenting that the code can give unexpected/wrong results when passed a non-sequence iterable. Actually, that should propably be done no matter if and how one tries to hack around this...

Comment: shouldn't it be `isinstance(obj, collections.Sequence)`?

Comment: So, in order to create a *correct* sequence class, should it subclass `collections.Sequence`? Does the `isinstance` function actually check if it subclasses the class, or does it only check to see if it implements the appropriate methods?

Comment: It checks if the object is an instance of a subclass or of a class that has been registered as a "virtual subclass" (see the abc module for info and further links http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). E.g. `isinstance({}, collections.Sequence)` yields `False`.