# json serialization of sqlalchemy association proxies

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I serialize SQLAlchemy mapped objects with `json.dumps`. And I'd like that my objects' [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) properties also get correctly serialized. They do not get correctly serialized by default, so I had to write a specific JSON encoder:

```python
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import _AssociationList
class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, _AssociationList):
            return list(obj)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

That does not look good, because I need to import `_AssociationList` which is private to SQLAlchemy.

Any other option?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the the _AssociationList specific type you could make a more general purpose test: is is "like" a list? Then serialize it as a list! (duck typing, see [Python: check if an object is a list or tuple (but not string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-or-tuple-but-not-string)).

```
def is_sequence(arg):
    return (not hasattr(arg, "strip") and
        hasattr(arg, "__getitem__") or
        hasattr(arg, "__iter__"))

class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if is_sequence(obj):
            return list(obj)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

That would treat sets, tuples, _AssociationLists and lists themselves as lists! But not string, ints and so on.