# Printing a 2D list in python without the commas

Tags: python, list

I'd like to print a 2D list in python without the commas.

Instead of printing

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1] ... ]
```

I want to print

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1] [1 1 1] ... ]
```

Any insight on how I should do the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Easy: just replace commas with spaces after converting to a string with `repr`.

```
def repr_with_spaces(lst):
    return repr(lst).replace(",", " ")
```

(This works for lists of integers, but not necessarily for anything else.)

Comment: EDIT: "Easy: just replace commas with spaces *after converting to string*"

Comment: mutzmatron: this worked even though it wasn't a list of strings

Comment: @user1249518 This will also break if your data contains commas.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general solution.  Convert a sequence into a string using a specified separator, and specified left and right bracketing characters.

```
lst = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1]]

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    basestring = str

try:
    from collections.abc import Iterable
except ImportError:
    from collections import Iterable


def str_seq(seq, sep=' ', s_left='[', s_right=']'):
    if isinstance(seq, basestring):
        return seq
    if isinstance(seq, Iterable):
        s = sep.join(str_seq(x, sep, s_left, s_right) for x in seq) 
        return s_left + s + s_right
    else:
        return str(seq)

print(str_seq(lst))
```

Why does the code have that `isinstance(seq, basestr)` check?  Here is why:

[How to check if an object is a list or tuple (but not string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-or-tuple-but-not-string/1835259#1835259)

Comment: I'd probably use `isinstance(seq, collections.abc.Iterable)` instead of the try/except.

Comment: I don't see a `collections.abc.Iterable` but I do see a `collections.Iterable`... when I checked, `isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)` succeeded where `x` is a list, an iterator, or a generator.  As long as you don't need to work with custom-made classes that don't bother to inherit from a suitable Python base type, the `isinstance()` check will work and should be noticeably faster.

Comment: `collections.abc` is Python 3.

Comment: @steveha: `isinstance(x, Iterable)` succeeds on any object that has an `__iter__` method. The `collections` ABCs use subclass hooks to customize `isinstance`.

Comment: Wow, this is what I like about StackOverflow.  Learning cool things like this.  So basically if `for x in foo` would succeed, then `isinstance(foo, Iterable)` would return `True`?  You guys have sold me on the idea.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @larsmans -- do I understand correctly that the `collections.abc.Iterable` is smarter than the `collections.Iterable` that is in Python 2.x?  Would it be possible, in Python 2.x, to "fool" the above code with a custom class that inherits only from `object` and defines its own methods so it works as an iterable?

Comment: @steveha: the 2.x version does this as well. Try defining a class with only an `__iter__` attribute, e.g. `class Foo(object): __iter__ = ()`. Then you'll find that `isinstance(Foo(), Iterable)` returns `True`.

Comment: @larsmans -- Okay, I read up on this a little more and now I understand it.  Python 2.6 introduced `collections.Iterable` and other abstract base classes in `collections`.  The code I originally wrote would work for Python 2.5 and older, but for Python 2.6 and newer I like this much better.  Anyone interested in abstract base classes should read the PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/

Comment: There is one case where this solution won't work, and the `try`/`except` would.  In Python, if you implement `.__getitem__()` in your class, it is iterable even if you do not implement `.__iter__()`.  I think I prefer the `Iterable` test anyway; if you want your class to be iterable, you should implement `.__iter__()`.  Great discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python

Answer (score 2):

A general, safe and recursive solution, that works if the data contains commas:

```
def my_repr(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return '[' + ' '.join(my_repr(x) for x in o) + ']'
    else:
        return repr(o)
```

The CPython implementation of `list_repr` uses essential this algorithm (using `_PyString_Join`).

Comment: This solution won't handle a tuple, an iterator, or a list-like object that doesn't inherit from `list`.  I guess the question was just about a `list`, but it is easy in Python to solve the general problem; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways:

```
your_string.replace(',',' ') 

' '.join(your_string.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a one-liner applied to array in variable "a":

```
print "[" + ' '.join(map(lambda row: "[" + ' '.join(map(str, row)) + "] ", a)) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join):

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

def format_list(items):
    list_contents = ' '.join(str(it) for it in items) # convert contents to string too
    return '[{}]'.format(list_contents) # wrap in brackets

formatted = format_list(format_list(l) for l in lists)
```

ideone example: http://ideone.com/g1VdE

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
str([1,2],[3,4]).replace(","," ")
```

what you wanted?