# python, wrap and object into a list if not is an iterable

Tags: python, loops, composite

I want to have a function that wraps and object in an iterable one in order to allow
the clients of the function treat the same way collections and single objects, i did the following:

```
 def to_iter(obj):
     try:
         iter(obj)
         return obj
     except TypeError:
         return [obj]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?, what if `obj` is a string and i want to treat strings as
single objects?, should i use `isinstance` instead `iter`?

Comment: "it's better to ask forgiveness than permission". Your code is okay unless you don't want to treat strings as iterables

Comment: so i have to use isinstace to check string objects? cause strings are iterables i can't have a list with a string in it with this code

Comment: This is a bad idea. The API for your function should just iterables. Callers can wrap single objects in a tuple or list if they need to. What if they want to treat an iterable other than a string as a single object — something you might not even know about?

Comment: @Twissell Yes, you may special case the iterable you want to treat as scalar.

Comment: @detly i feel is a good idea just cause the client dont have to check wheter the object is a collection or a single instance, so it can use the same interface for both.

Comment: @Twissell - They *should* have to know, though. They should certainly know what their own code is producing. Your own API should be documented. (Do you really think it's a good idea for people to just call your function with random stuff until it stops throwing exceptions?)

Comment: i see your point and feels right, but i am using this as a context for a template engine, so if i use a for loop in the template to render some object data i can render one or more objects without any additional change.

Comment: @Twissell - You know your own situation best, the only point I'm trying to make is that the extra complexity introduces edge cases you may not have thought about, and you might not be able to solve them once other code depends on this behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach is good: It would cast a string object to an iterable though

```
try:
    iter(obj)
except TypeError, te:
    obj = list(obj)
```

Another thing you can check for is:

```
if not hasattr(obj, "__iter__"): #returns True if type of iterable - same problem with strings
    obj = list(obj)
return obj
```

To check for string types:

```
import types
if not isinstance(obj, types.StringTypes) and hasattr(obj, "__iter__"):
    obj = list(obj)
return obj
```

Comment: hassattr and isinstance have the same behavior?, i can see that one raises and exception and the other is a boolean right?

Comment: both return a bool, and both are a fail-silently lookup.

Comment: `hasattr(obj, "__iter__")` **does not mean** iterable (you may add any stuff as this attribute). Also, if `iter` fails, `list` will also fail... And don't use the deprecated except syntax...

Comment: i know, but in this case, the sample code of karthikr is using hasattr in a boolean expresion instead using exceptions

Comment: is there any reason your storing the exception? and not using `as`?

Comment: nope.. no particular reason. Just a coding style, since it was not being used anyways @RyanHaining

Comment: @karthikr for your last code sample i just remove "not" for isinstance and added "or not" instead "and" for hasattr, now not iterable objects and strings are wrapped into a list

Comment: ok.. so dont make the changes you made, and it will work fine

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general solution with some doctests to demonstrate:

```
def is_sequence(arg):
    """
SYNOPSIS
    Test if input is iterable but not a string.

DESCRIPTION
    Type checker. True for any object that behaves like a list, tuple or dict
    in terms of ability to iterate over its elements; but excludes strings.

    See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018

PARAMETERS
    arg         Object to test.

RETURNS
    True or False

EXAMPLES
    ## string
    >>> is_sequence('string')
    False

    ## list
    >>> is_sequence([1, 2, 3,])
    True

    ## set
    >>> is_sequence(set([1, 2, 3,]))
    True

    ## tuple
    >>> is_sequence((1, 2, 3,))
    True

    ## dict
    >>> is_sequence(dict(a=1, b=2))
    True

    ## int
    >>> is_sequence(123)
    False

LIMITATIONS
    TBD
    """
    return (not hasattr(arg, "strip") and
            hasattr(arg, "__iteritems__") or
            hasattr(arg, "__iter__"))


def listify(arg):
    """
SYNOPSIS
    Wraps scalar objects in a list; passes through lists without alteration.

DESCRIPTION
    Normalizes input to always be a list or tuple.  If already iterable and
    not a string, pass through.  If a scalar, make into a one-element list.

    If a scalar is wrapped, the same scalar (not a copy) is preserved.

PARAMETERS
    arg         Object to listify.

RETURNS
    list

EXAMPLES
    >>> listify(1)
    [1]

    >>> listify('string')
    ['string']

    >>> listify(1, 2)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: listify() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

    >>> listify([3, 4,])
    [3, 4]

    ## scalar is preserved, not copied
    >>> x = 555
    >>> y = listify(x)
    >>> y[0] is x
    True

    ## dict is not considered a sequence for this function
    >>> d = dict(a=1,b=2)
    >>> listify(d)
    [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]

    >>> listify(None)
    [None]

LIMITATIONS
    TBD
    """
    if is_sequence(arg) and not isinstance(arg, dict):
        return arg
    return [arg,]
```

Comment: Perfect, but pretty much useless without is_sequence being defined.  I specifically needed to exclude strings, so my is_sequence looks like this:
```def is_sequence(arg):
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            return False
        if hasattr(arg, "__iter__"):
            return True```

Comment: You will want to use `basestr` instead of `str` if your code could be run in Python 2.x. `str` doesn't include Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

My portable pythonic hammer:

```
def isstr(o):
  try:
    basestring
  except NameError:
    basestring = (str, bytes)
  return isinstance(o, basestring)

def toiter(o):
  if not isstr(o):
    try:
      return iter(o)
    except TypeError:
      pass
  return iter([o])

def tolist(o):
  if not isstr(o):
    try:
      return list(o)
    except TypeError:
      pass
  return [o]
```