# How to test whether X quacks like a list/tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, iterable

How do we test whether X quacks like a list/tuple?

By that I mean we can possibly subset it by 0 and 1 (etc), though it cannot be a string (which could also be subset).

I thought to test `hasattr(X, '__iter__')` and `not isinstance(X, str)`, but that would mean a dictionary would still pass which I do not want it to. You could then also test it is not a dictionary, but I wouldn't be so sure about sublasses of dicts etc.

Is there a more official way to test whether something quacks like a list or tuple under this simple specification?

E.g. allowed input should be:

```
'emailaddr' --> ('emailaddr', 'emailaddr')
('emailaddr', 'alias')
['emailaddr', 'alias']
SequenceThing('emailaddr', 'alias')
```

Comment: What benefit will you gain from the (duck) type check?

Comment: Seems to me that a string is effectively/informally a tuple anyway. Can you give a practical example of a function where you would want to accept `('a', 'b', 'c')` as an argument, but reject `'abc'`?

Comment: I want to have an `('emailaddr@something', 'alias')` tuple, but also accept a list. I'd look up `X[0]` to get the email, and `X[1]` to get the alias. If only a string is given rather than a list or tuple, I'd assume the emailaddress is given and the alias should be equal to the emailaddress (if you can still follow, that would make `(X, X)`)

Comment: Include what you would want to be able to pass in to this hypothetical function, as what you're getting at is a bit difficult to infer just from the question alone.

Comment: But the thing is, I want to also allow "list-like" and "tuple-like" here, as long as it has index 0 and 1.

Comment: `isinstance(thing, collections.Sequence)` almost works, but it returns `True` for strings.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. It is clearly not duplicate because I am wanting to test whether it quacks like either of those, but not necessarily be equal to either.

Comment: @PascalvKooten quacks = "functions as" .... i misunderstood

Comment: If you want things that have `[0]` and `[1]` then you want strings too

Comment: @PascalvKooten: check if the value is a string.  If so, use it as a string.  Otherwise, access the [0] and [1] elements and use them.  If you get an exception, you get an exception.  No need to check first.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yea, that looks about right. I'm still curious though if there is not a more official way to test it rather than a solution that works for this specific case.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-or-tuple-but-not-string

Answer (score 2):

Would you like to check if a value is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)?

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the **getitem**() special method and defines a **len**() method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence types are list, str, tuple, and bytes. Note that dict also supports **getitem**() and **len**(), but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys rather than integers.

Old way (deprecated in 2.7):

```
import operator
print operator.isSequenceType(x)
```

New way:

```
import collections
print isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)
```

They are not equivalent - the latter is more accurate but custom types need to be [registered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) with it.

Also, strings are sequences according to both definitions. You might want to treat `basestring` specially.

Answer (score 2):

Don't allow a bare string as an argument; it's a special case waiting to bite you. Instead, document that the input must be in the form of a tuple/list/whatever, but the second element is optional. That is,

```
['emailaddr', ]
('emailaddr', )
SequenceThing('emailaddr')
```

are legal, but not

```
'emailaddr'
```

This way, your function can assume that `X[0]` will be an email address, and `X[1]` may exist and be an alias, but it is the user's problem if they supply something else.

Answer (score 1):

Duck typing means you just do want you want to do, and if it doesn't work it means you're not dealing with a duck.

If you specifically don't want to get strings, check for strings and raise an exception.

And then do whatever you want to do, no type checking.

Comment: Exactly, you throw the animal inside of the function, and if no exception is raised, then you got your duck!

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on Kevin's useful comment:

```
>>> import collections
>>> isinstance([], collections.Sequence) and not isinstance([], str)
True
>>> isinstance((), collections.Sequence) and not isinstance((), str)
True
>>> isinstance('', collections.Sequence) and not isinstance('', str)
False
>>> isinstance({}, collections.Sequence) and not isinstance({}, str)
False
>>> isinstance(set(), collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(set(), str)
False
```

Mappings such as dicts and sets will not pass the first test. Strings will, but they will obviously fail on the second test.

Comment: Python 3 can also use isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)

Comment: @JustinEngel Not for this case. Mappings are iterables, but not sequences, and the OP wants sequences alone.