# trying to flatten out a list in dictionary as key value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to flatten the aliases key out from Json

```
{
    "name": "Rocky Marci",
    "aliases": ["Rocky", "Champ"],
    "physical": {
        "height_in": 67,
        "weight_lb": 150
    },
    "Fights": 49
}
```

to like this below

```
{
    "name": "Rocky Marci",
    "aliases.0": "Rocky",
    "aliases.1": "Champ",
    "physical.height_in": 67,
    "physical.weight_lb": 150,
    "Fights": 49
}
```

I tried this

```
def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)
```

but this doesn't flatten out the array

Comment: Please show what output you want and what your are getting instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
s = {
 "name": "Rocky Marci",
 "aliases": ["Rocky", "Champ"],
 "physical": {
    "height_in": 67,
    "weight_lb": 150
  },
  "Fights": 49
}
def flatten(d, last = ''):
   for a, b in d.items():
     if type(b) in [int, str]:
       yield ("{}.{}".format(a, last) if last else a, b)
     if isinstance(b, list):
       for i, c in enumerate(b):
         yield ("{}.{}".format(a, i), c)
     if isinstance(b, dict):
        for i in flatten(b, last = a):
           yield i

result = dict(list(flatten(s)))
```

Output:

```
{'aliases.0': 'Rocky', 'height_in.physical': 67, 'name': 'Rocky Marci', 'aliases.1': 'Champ', 'Fights': 49, 'weight_lb.physical': 150}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because list is not an instance of `collections.MutableMapping`. I suggest checking

```
isinstance(v, (list, dict))
```

instead.

More possibilities are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835018/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-or-tuple-but-not-string)